# How to save DropDown selection with HTML5 storage?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, selection, local-storage

I have;

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
     <select name="country" class="dropdownselect" >

         <option value="">Select Country</option>   

             <option value="Afghanistan" selected="selected">Afghanistan</option>
             <option value="Albania" selected="selected">Albania</option>
             <option value="Algeria" selected="selected">Algeria</option>
     </select>
 </form>
```

And then in search.php;

```
$country = $country; 
+
SQL query for $country..
```

---

I need to save DropDown selection to stay selected when someones preform search.

Can it be done with HTML5 storage func?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can store it on select change and then read on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var item = window.localStorage.getItem('country');
    $('select[name=country]').val(item);

    $('select[name=country]').change(function() {
       window.localStorage.setItem('country', $(this).val());
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/McjJt/)

Comment: And how can I call it then to display selected value when someone preforms search? 

thanks for the feedback!

Comment: What you mean when someone performs search? If the page is reloaded, it gets selected automatically. If it's ajax search, it remains selected.

Comment: Everytime I do search ( <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">) the form reset's dropdown to default.. 

I tried codea above and it doesnt works..

Comment: How does the submit handler look like then? Could you update your question?

Comment: <form method="post" action="search.php">
     <select name="country" class="dropdownselect" >

         <option value="">Select Country</option>   

             <option value="Afghanistan" selected="selected">Afghanistan</option>
             <option value="Albania" selected="selected">Albania</option>
             <option value="Algeria" selected="selected">Algeria</option>
     </select>

<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="buttonsearch">

 </form> 

And then in PHP I have sql query.. 

Thanks Michal!